# biblatex-apa: for citations in text of the same author but different publications: shortauthor every time in [ ]

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa-style

I am using `biblatex-apa`with the `apa6.cls`.

In the text I cite several versions of the DSM (Diagnostic and Statistical Manual for Mental Disorders) by the American Psychiatric Association (APA):

```
@book{APA1994,
    author={{American Psychiatric Association}},
    shortauthor = {APA},
    year={1994},
    title="{Diagnostic and statistical manual of mental disorders: {DSM-IV}}",
    publisher={Autor},
    edition = {4th ed.},
    address={Washington, DC},
}

@book{APA2000,
    title = {Diagnostic and Statistical Manual of Mental Disorders: {DSM-IV-TR}},
    edition = {4th ed., text rev.},
    publisher = {Autor},
    author = {{American Psychiatric Association}},
    shortauthor = {APA},
    year = {2000},
    address={Washington, DC},
}

@book{APA2013,
    author = {{American Psychiatric Association}},
    shortauthor = {APA},
    address = {Washington, {DC}},
    edition = {5th ed.},
    title = {Diagnostic and statistical manual of mental disorders: {DSM-5}},
    publisher = {Autor},
    year = {2013},
}
```

When I first cite f. e.

`\parencite{APA1994}` I get the correct output:

> (American Psychiatric Association [APA], 1994)

When I cite that a second time, I get (which is also correct):

> (APA, 1994)

However, when I cite another publication with `\parencite{APA2000}` then after that, I get:

> (American Psychiatric Association [APA], 2000)

But, as this publication has the same author as cited before, I want the shortauthor to be put there, like:

> (APA, 2000)

How do I achieve that?

Comment: I consider this a bug in the APA style, you're right. It has been fixed in version 6.3 which I will mail you for testing if you like.

Comment: If this issue would be fixed in a regular version release soon I could wait until then. When will it be released?

Comment: Probably within a week or so.

Comment: Ah ok that's fine for me. Thanks for your info and offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those interested:

A new version of `biblatex-apa` fixed this issue, thanks to PLK.