# biblatex-apa: always use shortauthor in text

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I'm using `biblatex-apa` together with koma-script book class `scrbook`. Referring to the question [biblatex-apa: for citations in text of the same author but different publications: shortauthor every time in [ ]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140460/biblatex-apa-for-citations-in-text-of-the-same-author-but-different-publication), I'm trying to achieve that at every instance of citation of that organization in text prints the short author.

Assume the following minimal example

```
\documentclass[10pt,ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{OECD2009,
        title = {P{ISA} {D}ata {A}nalysis {M}anual: {SPSS}, {S}econd {E}dition},
        publisher = {OECD Publishing},
        year = {2009},
        author = {{Organisation for Economic Co-operation and Development}},
        address = {Paris},
        shortauthor = {{OECD}}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, natbib=true, refsegment=chapter, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\defcitealias{OECD2009}{OECD}

\begin{document}        
    first \cite{OECD2009} -- subsequent \cite{OECD2009}     
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

So when I first cite `\cite{OECD2009}` as well as every following occurrence, I would like to see

> OECD (2009)

(`\parencite` likewise). However the Reference section should include the entry using the full author

> Organisation for Economic Co-operation and Development. (2009). PISA Data Analysis Manual: SPSS, Second Edition. Paris: OECD Publishing.

How can I achieve that? As you can see, I already experimented with `\defcitealias` but I'm not too happy with that since I have to use `\citetalias` and `\citepalias` at every instance.

Any hint will be highly welcome

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the little piece of code

```
\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{\ifnameundef{shortauthor}{}{\def\cbx@apa@ifnamesaved{\@firstoftwo}}}
\makeatother
```

It resets the test to check if the name has been seen before to be true if a `shortauthor` is present. So you get to see the `shortauthor` even at the first citation.

MWE

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{OECD2009,
  title       = {P{ISA} {D}ata {A}nalysis {M}anual: {SPSS}, {S}econd {E}dition},
  publisher   = {OECD Publishing},
  year        = {2009},
  author      = {{Organisation for Economic Co-operation and Development}},
  address     = {Paris},
  shortauthor = {{OECD}},
}
@ARTICLE{7.01:7,
  AUTHOR         = {J. Chamberlin and A. Novotney and E. Packard and M. Price},
  TITLE          = {Enhancing Worker Well-being},
  SUBTITLE       = {Occupational Health Psychologists Convene to Share Their Research on Work, Stress, and Health},
  JOURNALTITLE   = {Monitor on Psychology},
  VOLUME         = {39},
  NUMBER         = {5},
  PAGES          = {26-29},
  DATE           = {2008-05}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, natbib=true, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{\ifnameundef{shortauthor}{}{\def\cbx@apa@ifnamesaved{\@firstoftwo}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}        
  \cite{OECD2009}

  \cite{OECD2009}   

  \cite{7.01:7}

  \cite{7.01:7}
  
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

> OECD, 2009
>
> OECD, 2009
>
> Chamberlin, Novotney, Packard, und Price, 2008
>
> Chamberlin u.a., 2008

Comment: that's exactly the kind of code I was hoping to find here someone able to produce. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user84164 Always a pleasure, never a chore.

Comment: Can this also be used in biblatex-chicago, or would it need modification?

Comment: @Erika You can try the code suggested here and if it works you are lucky, but the two styles are *very* different, so a solution for `biblatex-chicago` could be very different. If it doesn't work I suggest you ask a new question. (Well, looking at the code I'm almost 100% certain that it won't work for `biblatex-chicago` as-is.)

Comment: Fair enough! Here's the link to the new question, in case it's useful to anyone searching around here in future: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484298/always-use-shortauthor-in-text-with-biblatex-chicago

Comment: @jeanggi90 At least in the MWE my code seems to work fine. As far as I can see the only difference between my code and yours is `\def` vs `\let`. While the code is TeXnically not equivalent, it would greatly surprise me if the output were different. (I would love to see an example document.)

Comment: @moewe I am sure that I had this issue, but I am not able to reproduce it anymore (I do not have the document in the state where that happened anymore). Maybe it was also due some dangling build files or something the like.