# biblatex-apa: get the type of the @(tech)report when there is no number

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I'm still using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324144/biblatex-apa-always-use-shortauthor-in-text/) setup: `biblatex-apa`together with koma-script book class `scrbook`and here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,ngerman]{scrbook}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@report{aut1,
    author      = {Uthor, A.},
    title       = {Title title},
    year        = {1990},
    address     = {Paris},
    institution = {Organisation for Economic Co-operation {a}nd Development},
    type        = {Project report},
}
@report{aut2,
    author      = {Uthor, B.},
    title       = {Title title},
    year        = {1992},
    address     = {Paris},
    institution = {Organisation for Economic Co-operation {a}nd Development},
    type        = {Project report},
    number      = {2}
}
@techreport{aut3,
    author      = {Uthor, C.},
    title       = {Title title},
    year        = {1994},
    address     = {Paris},
    institution = {Organisation for Economic Co-operation {a}nd Development},
    type        = {Project report}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, natbib=true, refsegment=chapter, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}        
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

1) What I'm curios about is why I would not see the type of the report in the references when there is no number given, and how I can change that behavior. That is, in the references I would like to see

> Uthor, A. (1992). *Title title* (Project report). Organisation for Economic Co-operation and Development. Paris.

or/and

> Uthor, C. (1992). *Title title* (Project report). Organisation for Economic Co-operation and Development. Paris.

If possible, I would not want to make use of `@misc` or `@PhdThesis` since these would not adequately describe what the references technically are. I did try to use some way of a non-print-character like `~` in the `number` field but then I would just get something like

> .. (Project report Nr. ). ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex-apa` uses some intricate code to make sure to print the `type` field only if a number is present (obligatory warning: you may lose APA compliance if you modify the style in the way shown here). You can use

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{number}{\bibcpstring{number}~\apanum{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{apa:reportnum}{%
  \ifboolexpr{not test {\iffieldundef{type}} or not test {\iffieldundef{number}}}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printfield{type}%
       \setunit{\addspace}%
       \printfield{number}}}
    {}}
```

instead to print something if either the `type` or the `number` is present.

Naturally, you can use the redefinition

```
\renewbibmacro*{apa:reportnum}{%
  \iffieldundef{type}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printfield{type}%
       \setunit{\addspace}%
       \printfield{number}}}}
```

to avoid printing a lone number. (Which would be possible with the above.)

MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,ngerman]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@report{aut1,
    author      = {Uthor, A.},
    title       = {Title title},
    year        = {1990},
    address     = {Paris},
    institution = {Organisation for Economic Co-operation {and} Development},
    type        = {Project report},
}
@report{aut2,
    author      = {Uthor, B.},
    title       = {Title title},
    year        = {1992},
    address     = {Paris},
    institution = {Organisation for Economic Co-operation {and} Development},
    type        = {Project report},
    number      = {2}
}
@techreport{aut3,
    author      = {Uthor, C.},
    title       = {Title title},
    year        = {1994},
    address     = {Paris},
    institution = {Organisation for Economic Co-operation {and} Development},
    type        = {Project report}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{number}{\bibcpstring{number}~\apanum{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{apa:reportnum}{%
  \ifboolexpr{not test {\iffieldundef{type}} or not test {\iffieldundef{number}}}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printfield{type}%
       \setunit{\addspace}%
       \printfield{number}}}
    {}}

\begin{document}        
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

> Uthor, A. (1990). Title title (Project report). Organisation for Economic Co-operation and Development. Paris.
>
> Uthor, B. (1992). Title title (Project report Nr. 2). Organisation for Economic Co-operation and Development. Paris.
>
> Uthor, C. (1994). Title title (Project report). Organisation for Economic Co-operation and Development. Paris.

Comment: right on spot and fast as well. As always, thanks alot.