# Always use shortauthor in text with biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex-chicago

Based on this question – [biblatex-apa: always use shortauthor in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324144/biblatex-apa-always-use-shortauthor-in-text/) – I was wondering if it would be possible to achieve the same effect in `biblatex-chicago`, so that only the `shortauthor` form will appear in the text (while still, of course, being cited in full in the bibliography and shorthands list).

Here's what I'm working with:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[notes, backend=biber, sorting=nyt,
  giveninits=true, useprefix=false,
  shorthandibid, shorthandfull,
  addendum=false,
]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{jobname.bib}
@misc{ADLAe1658,
entrysubtype = {archival},
author = {{Archives départementales de Loire-Atlantique, Nantes}},
shortauthor = {{ADLA}},
title = {E 165-8},
keywords = {unpublished},
}

\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

This needs a citation.\autocite{lastname19}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off topic: Consider using `\jobname.bib` rather than `jobname.bib`. `\jobname` expands to the name of the current TeX file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to use `\AtEveryCitekey` to copy the `shortauthor` (if it exists) to `author`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[notes, backend=biber, sorting=nyt,
  giveninits=true, useprefix=false,
  shorthandibid, shorthandfull,
  addendum=false,
]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{ADLAe1658,
  entrysubtype = {archival},
  author = {{Archives départementales de Loire-Atlantique, Nantes}},
  shortauthor = {ADLA},
  title = {E 165-8}
}
@misc{ADLAe1658b,
  entrysubtype = {archival},
  author = {{Archives départementales de Loire-Atlantique, Nantes}},
  title = {E 165-8}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifnameundef{shortauthor}
    {}
    {\savename{shortauthor}{\tmpshortauthor}%
     \restorename{author}{\tmpshortauthor}}}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
This needs a citation.\autocite{ADLAe1658}

This needs a citation.\autocite{ADLAe1658b}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]