# Customized APA-like references with acronyms

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am using `biblatex` for my references. My goal is to have a style that is close to APA, but with some modifications:

1. In specific cases I want to have acronyms in this format:

RAE = Real Academia Española. (2011). *Nueva gramática básica de la lengua española*. Espasa.

The in-text citation should be RAE (2011).

2. I want to use : as a separator between the year and the page number in the citations. My current code does this now.

So far I have been using this (and it would be perfect if I could just add a "note" between the acronym and the year with the full name) but I was recommended not to use `style=apa` if I don't want to follow APA strictly.

```
\usepackage[style=apa,sorting=nyt,backend=biber,sortlocale=nb_NO,sortcites,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{: }%
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}%
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: If you want real APA style you should drop almost all of the package options: `sorting=nyt,` needs to go, because `style=apa,` has its own sorting scheme with a different name (which isn't used if you set the sorting to `nyt`, meaning you lose APA compliance). `sortlocale=nb_NO,` should also usually not be needed at all (no matter if you want APA style or not). `sortcites,` is  already set by `style=apa,`. `maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99` are also not required for APA style and may actually do harm.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{: }%` is a very crude redefinition. With a modern version of `biblatex` it should be `\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}`. But this definition would mean that you lose APA compliance. `\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}` should ideally be `\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}` on a modern system. But again, this setting is against APA style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, have you tried using `shortauthor`?

```
@book{rae2011,
    groupauthor = {{RAE = Real Academia Española}},
    shortauthor = {RAE},
    year = {2011},
    title = {Nueva gramática básica de la lengua española},
    publisher = {Espasa},
}
```

This will define the acronym the first time you cite it, and will use the acronym after that. In your case, I guess you prefer to always use the acronym. See: [biblatex-apa: always use shortauthor in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/324144)

Comment: Thank you, I did not know of `shortauthor`. I would like to have the acronym (and the full name, as some of them are rather unknown) in the reference list, but if I don't manage, this can be an option.

Comment: That's why I added the acronym in the `groupauthor` too :)

Comment: Right! I tried it with my own references that contained an `author` field and it looked as usual, but removing the `author` field works. It's giving me some touble though, I think it gets placed according to the title in the reference list (between N and P), and when I try with another reference and it shows "de Filología Aragonesa, E. =. E. " instead of "EFA = Estudio de Filología Aragonesa."

Comment: Did you use double braces in `groupauthor`?

Comment: For the sorting issue, remove the `sorting=nyt` option when loading the `biblatex` package.

Comment: Thanks so much for having the patience to help with all the little issues. That seems to solve everything. If you don't mind explaining, why does `sorting=nyt` cause that?

Comment: No idea. But the `biblatex-apa` documentation says you should load it as `\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}` and the only option supported is `apamaxprtauth`. This package follows the APA manual strictly. It is not to designed to allow customizations (which would break the rules).